# Ruby on Rails - JSON parse error unexpected token

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I read json file after load it into json but i got error **JSON::ParserError unexpected token at**, i couldn't json parse.Below i mentioned what i got output after file read

Here my code,

```
file = File.read("sample.json") 
hash = JSON.load(file)
```

after read my json file,

```
"{\"rename\"=>[{\"from\"=>\"TTTC\", \"to\"=>\"AAAB\"}, {\"from\"=>\"AAAA\", \"to\"=>\"Description\"}, {\"from\"=>\"AAAC\", \"to\"=>\"test\"}], \"drop\"=>{\"fields\"=>[\"AAAG\", \"AAAH\"]}}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not valid in json `=>`. JSON looks like

```
{ "rename": [{ "from": "TTTC" }] }
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not JSON that's a string created by applying the inspect method to a hash.

You can convert it back to a hash with eval

```
hash = eval(file)
```

However `eval` can be a security hole, so you should only do this if you're confident about the source and contents of the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're encountering this error while testing - make sure to add `.to_json` to your request's body hash.

Example:

```
headers = {
  'ACCEPTS' => 'application/json'
}

post '/api-endpoint-here', { name: 'Dylan Pierce' }.to_json, headers
```